# Array returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing an assignment where I have to make a slideshow using images, arrays, and some sort of timing feature of my choice, I'm getting stuck with the arrays because they keep returning as undefined whenever I use getElementById and from what I know it's because it thinks the id's don't exist even though they do, I'm not sure what the problem is and I can't move on and figure out the rest of the code because I can't get past this one thing.

Warning in advance, I'm pretty bad at coding JavaScript so this is probably going to look horribly wrong, but that's part of learning.

JavaScript:

```
let slides = document.getElementById[ 
    ["img1", "text1"],
    ["img2", "text2"],
    ["img3", "text3"],
    ["img4", "text4"],
    ["img5", "text5"],
    ["img6", "text6"],
    ["img7", "text7"],
    ["img8", "text8"],
    ["img9", "text9"],
    ["img10", "text10"]];
function slideShow() {
    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < slides[i].length; j++) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                slides.style.display = slides[i][j].Math.random()*11;
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}
slideShow();
```

Html to show that the id's do in fact exist:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>14_A_03
        </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="14_A_03.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text1">
                <h2>Orca
                    </h2>
                <p>Orcinus Orca<br><span class="small">Data Deficient</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img1">
                <img src="images/img-1-orca.jpg" width="600" alt="Orca jumping out of the water">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text2">
                <h2>Common Bottlenose Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Tursiops Truncatus<br><span class="small">Least Concern</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img2">
                <img src="images/img-2-common-bottlenose.jpg" width="600" alt="Two Common Bottlenose Dolphins swimming underwater together">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text3">
                <h2>Indo Pacific Humpback Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Sousa Chinensis<br><span class="small">Vunerable</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img3">
                <img src="images/img-3-indo-pacific-humpback.jpg" width="600" alt="Indo Pacific Humpback Dolphin jumping out of the water">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text4">
                <h2>Pacific White-Sided Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Lagenorhynchus Obliquidens<br><span class="small">Least Concern</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img4">
                <img src="images/img-4-pacific-whitesided.jpg" width="600" alt="Two Pacific White-Sided Dolphins jumping out of the water together">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text5">
                <h2>Dusky Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Lagenorhynchus Obscurus<br><span class="small">Data Deficient</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img5">
                <img src="images/img-5-dusky.jpg" width="600" alt="Dusky Dolphin jumping out of the water">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text6">
                <h2>Atlantic Spotted Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Stenella Frontalis<br><span class="small">Data Deficient</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img6">
                <img src="images/img-6-atlantic-spotted.jpg" width="600" alt="Two Atlantic Spotted Dolphins swimming underwater together">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text7">
                <h2>Atlantic White-Sided Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Lagenorhynchus Acutus<br><span class="small">Least Concern</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img7">
                <img src="images/img-7-atlantic-whitesided.jpg" width="600" alt="Atlantic White-Sided Dolphin jumping out of the water">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text8">
                <h2>Peale's Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Lagenorhynchus Australis<br><span class="small">Data Deficient</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img8">
                <img src="images/img-8-peales.jpg" width="600" alt="Peale's Dolphin jumping out of the water">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text9">
                <h2>Heaviside's Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Cephalorhynchus Heavisidii<br><span class="small">Data Deficient</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img9">
                <img src="images/img-9-heavisides.jpg" width="600" alt="Two Heaviside's Dolphins jumping out of the water">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div id="text10">
                <h2>Yangtze River Dolphin
                    </h2>
                <p>Lipotes Vexillifer<br><span class="small">Critically Endangered / Possibly Extinct</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div id="img10">
                <img src="images/img-10-baiji.jpg" width="600" alt="Yangtze River Dolphin looking through the surface of the water">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="14_A_03.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried quite a few different solutions but I just can't get past the array returning as undefined and since it's required in the assignment I need to make sure it doesn't keep happening.

**Edit**
Okay that was fast, problem solved, thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: You didn't call the method `getElementById`. You're using an array to index into it.

Comment: so, calling it would be getElementById([array stuff]); then from what I can tell? then it starts returning null instead

Comment: Obviously you don't know a lot of javascript, and some web API of javascript. `getElementById(String: id)` only accept a string as argument. Either you call `getElementsByClassName` and take 1st and 2nd elements, or you call `getElementById` multiple times for each image and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` only takes one argument, so if you want to call it for each value in your 2d array, you should use:

```js
let slides = [
    ["img1", "text1"],
    ["img2", "text2"],
    ["img3", "text3"],
    ["img4", "text4"],
    ["img5", "text5"],
    ["img6", "text6"],
    ["img7", "text7"],
    ["img8", "text8"],
    ["img9", "text9"],
    ["img10", "text10"]].map(
      (item) => [
         document.getElementById(item[0]), 
         document.getElementById(item[1])
      ]
    );
```

Also note that calling a function requires you to use round brackets (`()`) and not square brackets (`[]`)

Comment: Good answer. but I'm afraid the rest of OP codes lack of javascript knowledges. Mainly at `.Math.random()`.